# Orthogonal complement is the set of vectors orthogonal to the rows of matrix A. Why?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, inner-products, orthogonality

When reading about orthogonal complement, I encounter the following claim:

> If the subspace is described as the range of a matrix: $S = \{ Ax : x
>  \in \Bbb R^n \}$, then the orthogonal complement is the set of
>   vectors orthogonal to the rows of A, which is the nullspace of $A^T$.

I don't quite understand how we can make the above claim from the definition of orthogonal complement as the set of vectors that are orthogonal to all $Ax$. Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 1):

Let $C_1,\ldots,C_p$ be  the columns of the matrix $A$, then $S=\operatorname{span}(C_1,\ldots,C_p)$, hence $x\in S^{\perp}$ iff $\langle C_i,x\rangle =0,\;\forall i\in \{1,\ldots,p\}$ iff $A^{T}x=0$. (the lines of $A^{T}$ are the columns of $A$).

Comment: Perhaps I'm being dull here but how is $S = span(C_1, \dots, C_n)$? Vectors in $S$ has length $n$, whereas $C_1, \dots, C_n$ has length k (with k being the number of columns in A). How could vectors in S be linear combinations of $C_1, \dots, C_n$ then?

Comment: Is $A$ a square matrix?

Comment: I see no mention of A being square in the original source https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/def_orth_compl.html

Comment: Do you know that $Ax=x_1C_1+\ldots+x_nC_n$?

Comment: I was taught the contrary, that's why I'm confused. I was taught that "columns of AB are linear combination of columns of A, using col of B as coefficient." So in this case, $Ax$ should be lin.comb. of $A$'s cols, not $A$'s row.

Comment: @Heisenberg, vectors in $S$ are $m$-dimensional, where $m$ is the number of rows in A.